# clang-format function argument indent

Tags: clang-format

Is there a way to configure clang-format to behave in this way? Notice how each parameter is on its own line and is indented by only 1 level as opposed to aligned with the function name. This is my preferred coding style, but I just can't get clang-format to do this.

```
int a_very_long_function_name(                                                                        
    int var_a,                                                                      
    double my_b,                                                                      
    char *str                                                                       
) {                                                                             
    int d = 0;
    /* ... */                                                           
    return d;                                                       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be possible now according to: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

`AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent`

Comment: Spectacular! I'm adding this option to all my projects now!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

You can try all the different parameters with this nifty tool: https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/